# Java Calculator Type of equation not working

Tags: java

NEED HELP
i'm trying to make a calculator with Java using Eclipse IDE
type of equation not working please help
(Java)

CODE:

package GUI;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner Type = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner First = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner Second = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
    System.out.println("Input one number");
    int first = First.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input Second number");
    int second = Second.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("What type of equation would you like to do: + - * /");
    Type.next();
    
    if(Type.equals("+")) {
        
        System.out.println(first + second);
    }
    
    if(Type.equals("-")){
        System.out.println(first - second);

    }
    
    if(Type.equals("*")){
        System.out.println(first * second);

    }
   
    if(Type.equals("/")){
        System.out.println(first / second);

    }
    First.close();
    Second.close();
    Type.close();
}
```

}

Comment: You do no need multiple Scanner's. Just use the one.

Comment: What is your error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See when you define `Scanner Type = new Scanner(System.in);`? That means that `Type` has a type of `Scanner`. When you do `Type.equals`, you're comparing a Scanner with a String (which it'll never be equal). You should do something like that:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // You can use just one scanner, not three
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Input one number");
    int first = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input Second number");
    int second = scanner.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("What type of equation would you like to do: + - * /");
    
    // Save what was entered into a variable, the same
    // way you're doing with the `first` and `second` variables
    String operation = scanner.next();
    
    // Compare using the `operation` variable, not the `scanner`
    if (operation.equals("+")) { 
        System.out.println(first + second);
    }
    // Also, use else-ifs to avoid unnecessary checks
    else if(operation.equals("-")){
        System.out.println(first - second);
    }
    else if (operation.equals("*")){
        System.out.println(first * second);
    }
    else if(operation.equals("/")){
        System.out.println(first / second);
    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

When comparing, you can also use a [switch-case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: Thank you for the help I tried it and I cant input after  System.out.println("What type of equation would you like to do: + - * /"); Discord: Void#0897

Comment: @Void Updated, see if it solves your problem now (just replace `scanner.nextLine()` with `scanner.next()`).

Comment: Thank you so much beginner in java coming from c# thank you and you were so quick with responses you responded like really quick thanks -discord Void#0897